# Xamarin forms themes

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

After merging with light theme resources, the navigation bar color has been changed. How to change the color of the navigation bar after merging with light theme resources?

Comment: Can any1 give a idea atleast??

Comment: Which OS do you experience the issue on? Some more details in your question may be helpful. And did you read the documentation? For a [`NavigationPage`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage/), you can set a Property called `BarBackgroundColor`.

Comment: Im developing xamarin forms application and presently im targeting android and recently i have added Xamarin.forms.Themes.LightTheme and also i have merged the application with the light theme but previously the tabbar and action bar color was something like green, now after merging the color automatically set to color like light blue, but i dont want the color to be changed..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" <-------- check the value of this 
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

This color should define the color of the navigation bar.

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#a5d6f7</item> <------- light blue
```

Comment: Yes i have done this previously when i dint use theme after merging themes then i experienced the issue.Before merging the theme everything was fine but after merging theme the issue occurs.

Comment: Can you post your tablayout setup?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

Comment: Even now i took a new project and added Xamarin.Forms.Themes. dlls and i have added resources in the app.Xaml file as                                                       <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary MergedWith="light:LightThemeResources"/>
        <!-- Application resource dictionary -->

 </Application.Resources>

Comment: and also added in the mainactivity as                                                   var x = typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Themes.DarkThemeResources);
            x = typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Themes.LightThemeResources);
            x = typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Themes.Android.UnderlineEffect);

            LoadApplication (new AppTesting.App ());

Comment: and here <item name="colorPrimary">#3E49CB</item>